# iOS $.post Jquery not working

Tags: jquery, ios, post, hybrid

Ive got a hybrid app going on both android and ios phones,
and the problem i got, is that some of the `$.post` is not working in ios.

I have tested it on:

- Windows PC Chrome - OK
- Windows PC Safari - OK
- Android APP - OK
- Android Browser - OK
- iPhone App - Not working
- iPhone Safari - Not working
- iPad Safari - Not working

There are 2 out of 10 posts that isnt working, using the same code, just the url that is diffrent.
one of the url that isnt working is kind of long, has around 20 parameters,
the otherone has around 5.

So cant be any of that?

Any ideas what can be the problem with this?

Comment: Can you add the url that goes wrong? Got some code for us?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it:
When android or windows send javascript date in url it comes as:
2012-11-1 10:16:48.123

When iOS sends it:
2012-11-1 10:09:04 CET.733

And when i tried to DateTime.Parse the ios one, it said:
"The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is an unknown word starting at index 19."